# Android Studio - Multiple errors in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, live-wallpaper

Errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I am creating Live Wallpaper type app. I have include following module for app.

> AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter
>
> AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension-GLES2-AnchorCenter

Here is manifest.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="inapppurchase.com.mylivewallpaper">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
    android:glEsVersion="20000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
     android:name="inapppurchase.com.mylivewallpaper.LiveWallpaperService"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="inapppurchase.com.mylivewallpaper.WallpaperPreference"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Wallpaper setting">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="inapppurchase.com.mylivewallpaper.GDWallpaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What did the logs say the multiple errors are?  We aren't going to guess them

Comment: @GabeSechan this is error log.-->Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
     build file '/media/user86/data1/Sanwal Projects/AndroidStudioWS/MyLiveWallpaper/other_lib/AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter/build.gradle': 35: unexpected token: < @ line 35, column 8.
     <application/>     resources.srcDirs = ['src']
     ^
     1 error
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4s 575ms)

Comment: `unexpected token: < @ line 35, column 8`... So, your XML is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MergedManifest section of AndroidManiefst.xml.

On the right, you can see the specific errors (If Any). Try to resolve those.

[image]